# How can I fix Intellisense issues with Python's openCV on vsCode

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am somewhat new to Python and I am starting to explore openCV and numpy for object detection. It's all going well and I understand it well, however I am using vsCode and when I initialize the value:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

the autocomplete/Intellisense does not render in the future. For example when I try:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

on line 10 or

```
cap.release()
```

on line 27, it does register as being a correct function. The code all still works, so it's not the end of the world, just wondering if this issue can be fixed?

All code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

lowerBound = np.array([15, 150, 20])
upperBound = np.array([35, 255, 255])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lowerBound, upperBound)


    cnts, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(cnts) != 0:
        for c in cnts:
            if cv2.contourArea(c) > 500:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows
        break
```

Comment: It could be a couple of things. What tool are you using for your virtual env?

Comment: Please paste your code instead of using a screenshot. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Language Server does not support [get Intesllisense from the pyd file](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1711) for now.

[image]

[image]