# Code editor not displaying suggestions for functions when working with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I just installed opencv and was following a tutorial and realized that when I type down `capture.` vscode is not giving me the suggestions for the functions available for the 'capture' pointer. It is, however, showing me sugestions from the cv2 library.

[This is what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPht8.png)

but

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hl6B.png)

So my question basically is, How can I fix this? I havnet been able to find any solution online. I want to be able to see what functions are available so I can learn and explore the library better.

Here's the complete code, just in case:

```
import cv2 as cv

capture = cv.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    isTrue, frame = capture.read() #grab video frame by frame
    cv.imshow('Camera', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break

capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you aren't the first to ask this. browse here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code%2bopencv%2bpython?tab=Votes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix Intellisense issues with Python's openCV on vsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760087/how-can-i-fix-intellisense-issues-with-pythons-opencv-on-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760087/how-can-i-fix-intellisense-issues-with-pythons-opencv-on-vscode).

Python Language Server does not support **Intesllisense** from the `.pyd` file for now.